Error Forming a Boxplot and Scatterplot using 3 Variables in ggplot
I'm trying to work through a problem that I keep encountering in R, where when I try to create a side-by-side boxplot as well as a scatterplot of three variables. I am using the dataset "Boston" located in the ISLR2 package, and I am unsure why the graphs look so weird. For the side-by-side boxplot, I am creating the plot 'medv' by two variables, 'cat_chas' and 'cat_rm', which are both direct mutations of the variables 'chas' and 'rm' in the Boston dataset. For the scatterplot, I am using the variable 'age' on the horizontal axis and 'medv' on the vertical axis, with the points being colored by the variable 'cat_rm'. Is it something simple I am making a mistake on?
Side-by-side Boxplot
library(ISLR2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

data = data.frame(Boston)
data <- mutate(data, cat_chas = chas, cat_rm = rm)


ggplot(data, aes(x=cat_chas, y=medv)) +

  geom_boxplot(fill="green", color="black") +

  facet_wrap(~ cat_rm, ncol=3) +

  labs(title="Boxplot of medv by cat_chas and cat_rm",

       x="cat_chas",

       y="Median Value ($1000s)") +

  theme_minimal()


Boxplot output
Scatterplot
library(dplyr)
ggplot(BSTN, aes(x = age, y = medv, color = cat_rm)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Scatter plot of MEDV", color = "Category RM", x = "Age", y = "MEDV") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color = "blue", size = 17), plot.background = element_rect(fill = "orange"))


Scatterplot output
I thought the problem could be that I am using a data frame instead of a data set, so I tried switching it around, but I still get the same result.

If you check length(unique(Boston$rm)) you will find there are 446 unique values. Therefore, your boxplot code is attempting to construct a faceted grid of 149 x 3 panels which is far too many facets to partition the available data into.

As per your scatterplot, you have not provided a definition of BSTN, but based on the linked image, it appears you have set cat_rm as a factor/character/categorical. Therefore, the legend showing each individual level is taking up all the available plot space. Instead, leave it as a numeric to map a continuous variable to a continuous color scale.

Thank you for your help! Those explanations make sense and I will see if I can fix those problems! You're a lifesaver!

That worked perfectly for the scatter plot. Thanks, I've been stuck on this for a few days

In the boxplot, it seems that your variables are not right:
$ cat_rm   <dbl> 6.575, 6.421, 7.185, 6.998, 7.147, 6.430, 
Variable cat_rm is numeric with too many different values to be meaningfully used inside a facet_wrap function or as a color in the scatterplot.
This is why you get a (i) separate window for each value of cat_rm.
Your dataset used in ggplot() is BSTN. It is not part of the packages you provided in your example code. Should it be data? If I use data as dataset within ggplot():
ggplot(data, aes(x = age, y = medv, color = cat_rm)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(title = "Scatter plot of MEDV", color = "Category RM", x = "Age", y = "MEDV") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(color = "blue", size = 17), plot.background = element_rect(fill = "orange"))

I get the following result:


Seems I wasn't fast enough :) Same as what the-mad-satter said.

Thank you for your help as well! I appreciate what you both worked on to help me!
